# How to make a bootable usb stick and cd disk?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, livecd, cd

so the operating system does not work on one of my laptops due to some reason. However I decided that I want to put the operating system on again. I have a USB drive and 8gigabyte CD disks and would like know how to make them both bootable. Your help will be well appreciated and i look forward to seeing your replies.

Thank you very much, 
Abdullah